# In iOS, if all the task can only be executed asynchronously on a serial queue, isn't it essentially becomes a concurrent queue?

Tags: ios, concurrency

according to apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html), tasks are still started in the order in which they were added to a concurrent queue, so it seems to me that there is no difference between a concurrent queue vs a serial queue where all its task are run by async.

correct me if I miss something

read bunch of documents and did not find the answer

Answer (score 0):

The difference is how many tasks may run *at the same time*:

A serial queue only processes (runs) one task at time, one after another. A concurrent queue may process multiple tasks (on multiple thread) at the same time.

You typically use a serial queue to ensure only one task is accessing a resource at the same time. These are scenarios where you would traditionally use mutexes.

If you have tasks that would benefit from (and are able to) running *concurrently* at the same time, or tasks that are completely independent and thus don't care, you usually use a concurrent queue.

Comment: so if I run below code 
serialQueue.async {A},serialQueue.async {B},serialQueue.async {C}

A,B,C are started in order, but they are executed in parallel, my question is: isn't that essentially what the con concurrent queue is doing in iOS?

Comment: @Flowriverdrytree: No, with a serial queue they are started in order and run one after another (serially, not parallel). Task B is only started after after task A has completed, and task C is only started after B is completed. A concurrent queue allows all three tasks to run at the same time (concurrently/parallel).